# Use WinSCP to upload from a folder with a fiscal year in its name to an SFTP server

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I am currently running a batch file that contains a WinSCP command line that uploads a file from a child folder to an SFTP server.  The command is scripted as such:

```
put ""C:\Finance\FY 2021\%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%\file.txt"" ^
```

The problem is, the parent folder (`FY 2021`) changes every October 1. So I currently will set a task to manually modify the path to `FY 2022`, `FY 2023` and so on, at the end of the day on September 30.  Is there a way to script the command so this change could be automated?  Change meaning the target directory path.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [future timestamp syntax of WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp). There are 61 days to the end of the year after [October 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_1). So if you add 62 days to a timestamp, the calendar year of the resulting timestamp will be equal to the fiscal year of the original timestamp.

With that knowledge, the following will produce the fiscal year: `%TIMESTAMP+62D#yyyy%`

In your batch file, you can use it like this:

```
  "put ""C:\Finance\FY %%TIMESTAMP+62D#yyyy%%\%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%\file.txt"" ^
```

Comment: Did not even think of that!  Thanks so much!